# CMS for django application which does not use django admin app

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm developing a django application which does not uses django's built in admin interface. Instead I'm using my own custom admin interface. I need a simple cms to create and edit pages like 'about' and some simple pages displaying some texts and images. I checked some cms described [here](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/). But all of them works with django's admin interface. Is there any cms packages that I can use with my custom admin interface? I'm using django 1.7 and python 3

Comment: do you know about django-cms

Comment: @joelgoldstick Not much.. I tried a basic installation of django-cms.. Thats it.  Is there any option to use django-cms without default admin interface?

Answer (score -1):

in short, no real application; but you can try django-ckeditor https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor
which makes it really easy to create a simple CMS form page

Example:

```
class CMSPage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body = models.TextField(...)
    ...

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CMSPage
        exclude = ('id',)
        widgets = { 'body': CKEditorWidget(config_name='default') }
```

and when you load the form, it will have a WYSIWYG editor!

Comment: not sure what is wrong with this answer... it is by far the easiest solution to the problem asked.  The only other method for a really simple CMS that would integrate into a custom admin code would be to manually add the ckeditor (or other javascript/jquery package that turns textarea's into wysiwyg editors).